# div display based on button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jsfiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/Jsh2V/10/

The first sets of test buttons ("show it" and "hide it") work great.  I have been trying to get the second set of buttons ("Have it" and "Need it") to do the same thing with a div.  Not working. Any suggestions?  Also, if theres a more efficient way to do this...

Here the code from the Fiddle:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
      p { background:yellow; }
      </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <button class="1">Show it</button>
  <button class="2">Hide it</button>

      <p style="display: none" class="1">Hello</p>
      <p style="display: none" class="2">Un Hello!</p>
<script>
    $("button.1").click(function () {
    $("p.1").show("slow");
    $("p.2").hide("fast");
    });
</script>
<script>
    $("button.2").click(function () {
    $("p.1").hide("fast");
    $("p.2").show("slow");
    });
</script>


    <button class="have">Have</button>
    <button class="need">Need</button>

    <div id="have" style="display: none">HAVE YO</div>
    <div id="need" style="display: none">NEED YO</div>
<script>
    $("button.have").click(function () {
    $("div.have").show("slow");
    $("div.need").hide("fast");
    });
</script>
<script>
    $("button.need").click(function () {
    $("div.need").show("slow");
    $("div.have").hide("fast");
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should be `div#have` instead of `div.have`, since your divs have an id of `have`, not a class of `have`.

```
<script>
    $("button.have").click(function () {
    $("div#have").show("slow");
    $("div#need").hide("fast");
    });
</script>
<script>
    $("button.need").click(function () {
    $("div#need").show("slow");
    $("div#have").hide("fast");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/SfXVA/

You used ID's for the second 2 divs, therefore you needed to reference them with # (for IDs) instead of . (for classes) in your selector.

[EDIT]

Additionally, you do not need to do 'div#have', just '#have' would suffice, since ID's SHOULD be unique in the DOM.